# I typed in a shellscript program to generate table of a number. I am using onworks (online os platform)

Tags: shell

I am really new to shell, been doing it since yesterday and I can't figure out what's wrong.
Here's the code:

```
echo "Enter a Number"
read n
i=1

while [ $i -le 10 ]
do
          echo " $n x $i = $(( n * i ))"
          i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

And here's the error message:
while[1-le 10]: command not found; and,
syntax error near unexpected token 'do'

Comment: you need to specify which shell to use as the first line: `#!/bin/bash`, for example

Comment: I tried, it still doesn't work

Comment: How you start the script?

Comment: Write your code in the text editor. Save as .sh. Then access your program from the terminal. Or you may use an online compiler.